# nth-of-type but ignore some elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If you have this html:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qujo0w00/

```
<article class="type-a">Content A</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
<article class="type-a">Content A</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
<article class="type-a">Content A</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
<article class="type-b">Content B</article>
```

How do you target every second element that HAS type-b class? Because, if you use

```
.type-b:nth-of-type(2n+2) { background-color: red; }
```

it targets the 2nd article, even if the first article doesn't have type-b class. And then it seems to work randomly, skipping 3 articles at one point.

I'm really confused over what is going on, can anyone shed any light on this?

I even tried:

```
article:not(.type-a):nth-of-type(2n+2) { background-color: red; }
```

but still same issue.

Comment: It targets childrens, doesn't matter how classname you are defined. `nth-of-type(n)` reffers to the `n` children, not the `n with classname x` children. To make this task you need to change the html or make in javascript

Comment: In addition to Marcos' comment, you may want to have a look at BoltClock's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class). It would explain how the `nth-*` selectors work.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now, and I will change the HTML structure.